# Virtual functions with default argument unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I was recently trying to understand how virtual functions work, so I decided to try to run the following code.

```
#include <iostream>


class Base {
public:
    virtual void f(int i = 10) const {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void f(int i = 20) const override{
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base* pb = &d;
    pb->f();   // prints 10
    d.f();     // prints 20
    return 0;
}
```

The result surprised me, I expected that both functions should print 20 on console, which, unfortunately, did not take place.

The result was as follows

```
10
20
```

Can someone please explain what happened there?

Thank you in forward.

Comment: We ask this at our interviews. :P

Comment: The first uses the `Base` interface and the second the `Derived` interface, and those have different default values.